# Selenium not clicking on webelements sometimes

Tags: python, selenium, wait

This is the code I have that works about 80 percent of the time. But sometimes what happens is that the script hovers to the first element, moves to the drop down menu element and then proceeds to not click.

However, the script seems to think it has clicked the element and the print message shows up with no exception occurring. Is there anyway I can write some code to confirm the button has been clicked, and if it is not clicked keep trying to click it?

```
#click on sourcekey->view tender
time.sleep(20)
sourcekey = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[text()='Source Key']")))
view_tender = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//a[text()='View RFQ/Tender/RFP'] ")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(sourcekey).double_click(view_tender).perform()   
print("Click on view tender")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)

sourcekey = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[text()='Source Key']")))      
    
actions.move_to_element(sourcekey).perform()
    
view_tender = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//a[text()='View RFQ/Tender/RFP'] ")))
actions.double_click(view_tender).perform()   

print("Click on view tender")
```

Try using visibility of element than presence, the action class might try to click the element before it is visible

Comment: wont work because its a drop menu option and it only appears when I hover over another element

Comment: @BobTin updated the answer could you try reordering your steps

Comment: does rearranging the steps works for you ?